# Iterate through children of multiple set of elements (class) simultaneously

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, each

I try to cycle through multiple lists of blockquotes simultaneously. The effect should be just as you can see it on the [Commercial Type](http://commercialtype.com/typefaces) site: You see only one `blockquote` per `.quotes` and after a delay it goes to the next `blockquote` one `.quotes` after the other.

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="quotes">
        <blockquote>Blockquote 1</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 2</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 3</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 4</blockquote>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="quotes">
        <blockquote>Blockquote 1</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 2</blockquote>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="quotes">
        <blockquote>Blockquote 1</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 2</blockquote>
        <blockquote>Blockquote 3</blockquote>
    </div>
</section>
```

Within each `.quotes` the blockquotes should cycle through infinitely. The thing I'm stuck with is that I don't know how I can iterate simultaneously over a group of `.quotes`. All solutions I found only target one container (usually with an id).

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.quotes').each(function(idx){
    var $quote = $(this);
    $quote.children().hide();

    function showFirst(){
        var $first = $quote.children().first().fadeIn('slow').delay(2500).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            setTimeout(showFirst);
            $first.appendTo($quote)
        })
        }

    setTimeout(showFirst, idx * 100);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JPwkz/)

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Is it possible to also include a small delay between updating the different `.quotes` (just like on [Commercial Type](http://commercialtype.com/typefaces))? Right now every `.quotes` is updated at the very same moment.